# How to change data of jlabel on button click?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Hi i am trying to make java desk top application  where i am  using  2 jpanel in that 2 jpanel i am drawing jlabel

i am having button next i want when i click button next   jlabel  data should change  how can i do this

here is my code

```
public Second() {
          this.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 140, 0));
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
this.setUndecorated(true);

            initComponents();


             JPanel panel = createPanel(); 
        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
//         jPanel1.setLayout(null);
     jPanel1.add(panel);

     JPanel panel1 = createPanel(); 
        jPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
//  jPanel2.setLayout(null);
     jPanel2.add(panel1);


      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
   //get current date time with Date()
   Date date = new Date();
   //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); don't print it, but save it!
   String yourDate = dateFormat.format(date);
       jButton7.setText(yourDate);
         jButton6.setText(yourDate);
       jButton5.setText(yourDate);
       jButton1.setText(yourDate);

    }


     private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 5));
        EmptyBorder panelBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 5, 10, 10);
       panel.setBorder(panelBorder);
 panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 51));
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        EmptyBorder border1 = new EmptyBorder(15, 20, 15, 18);
       // LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
     //   CompoundBorder compound = new CompoundBorder(line, border);
          Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i <11; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CaseNum<br><font color=yellow>Party1<br>Party2</font></html>");
  label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18));
           label.setBorder(border);

           label.setBorder(border1);

           label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
             label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255,255 ));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        return panel;
    }
```

How can i achieve my desired output

my updated code

```
 public Second() {
              this.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 140, 0));
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setUndecorated(true);

                initComponents();


                 JPanel panel = createPanel(); 
            jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //         jPanel1.setLayout(null);
         jPanel1.add(panel);

         JPanel panel1 = createPanel(); 
            jPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //  jPanel2.setLayout(null);
         jPanel2.add(panel1);


          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); don't print it, but save it!
       String yourDate = dateFormat.format(date);
           jButton7.setText(yourDate);
             jButton6.setText(yourDate);
           jButton5.setText(yourDate);
           jButton1.setText(yourDate);

        }


         private JPanel createPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 5));
            EmptyBorder panelBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 5, 10, 10);
           panel.setBorder(panelBorder);
     panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 51));
            panel.setOpaque(true);
            EmptyBorder border1 = new EmptyBorder(15, 20, 15, 18);
           // LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
         //   CompoundBorder compound = new CompoundBorder(line, border);
              Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2);
            for (int i = 0; i <11; i++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CaseNum<br><font color=yellow>Party1<br>Party2</font></html>");
      label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18));
               label.setBorder(border);

               label.setBorder(border1);

               label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                 label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255,255 ));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                panel.add(label);
            }
            return panel;
        }


private void NextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    label.setText("new text");
}
```

on every click of button i want

```
1 click "hello";
2 click "sharma"
3 click " not  bad";
4 click " not good"

and so on
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("new text");
        }
    });
```

Will change the text of `label` to `new text` when `button` is clicked.

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        int clicks = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (++clicks) {
                case 1:
                    label.setText("hello");
                break;

                case 2:
                    label.setText("sharma");
                break;

                //continue doing it like this
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am using netbeans  ide

Comment: Er, you're doing it wrong. Go to your UI designer and right click your button, then go to events and then to action. Then click actionPerformed and add `yourlabel.setText("text");` in there. Look at the image in my original post.

Comment: i did this but changing is made in onluy only label and  there more then one label are avaiilable

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please rephrase? I don't understand what you're saying. If you want to change the text of more than one label simply add more statements. `label2.setText("sdfsdf"); label3.setText("3242");` etc..

Comment: i used for loop for creating  many jlabel  not indivisually  making lable

Comment: Well you need some way to keep track of those labels. The simplest solution is storing them in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: How can i could u  tell me

Comment: Create an `ArrayList` object in your class using `ArrayList<JLabel> lbllist = new ArrayList<>();` then add `lbllist.add(label);` after `panel.add(label);` in your code and in the `actionPerformed` method do something like `for (JLabel label: lbllist) { label.setText("hello"); }` If it still doesn't work, please update your code after you've done this.

Comment: it is working  one more prob is here that i want to change label on every click  is it possible

Comment: You mean when you click any of the buttons? If yes, just add ActionListeners to the other buttons too.

Comment: no i mean on same button if i click 5 times then label should change five times

Comment: What should it change to? With the code you have now, it does change the text every time, but it changes it to the same text, so you can't really tell.

Comment: what change should i make to  achieve this

Comment: Depends on what you're changing the text to. What do you want the text to be after the clicks?

Comment: i want just normal text on every click  only text should change thats it

Comment: Can you give me an example? For example 1st click - text should be "1" then 2nd click text should be "4" then 3rd click text should be "9" etc, so I can see what you're doing and tell you how to do it.

Comment: i did not get  mean by origimal post

Comment: er i meant that i updated mine. the solution is in the post at the top.